# make item use remaining space for width

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the text and the input on 1 line where the input field takes up the total width of the remaining space.

So not this:

[image]

The only solution I did found was `overflow: hidden`, but I don't like that since it being a text input.

Is it possible? And if yes, how?

Please no use `90%` solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/aLmctj4h/

```
  <div id="container">
        foobar: <input type="text" value="foobar" />
    </div>

    #container {
        background: #ccc;
        width: 640px;
        min-height: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    input {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

CSS:

```
#container {
background: #ccc;
width: 640px;
min-height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
}

label {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
}
span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
input {
    width: 100%
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<label>foobar:</label>
<span><input type="text" value="foobar" /></span>
</div>
```

You can make foobar a label and change the width a little to adjust for the size if I understood your question right.

Comment: Why does it need a span and doesn't it work when the span properties are set on the `input {}`?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
 .div-table {
   width:100%;
   display: table;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 .div-table .div-table-row {
   display: table-row;
 }

 .div-table .div-table-cell {
   display: table-cell;
 }

 .nostretch {
   width:1%;
   white-space:nowrap;
 }

 input {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="container">
     <div class='div-table'>
         <div class='div-table-row'>
             <div class='div-table-cell nostretch'>foobar:</div>
             <div class='div-table-cell'>
                 <input type="text" value="foobar" />
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLmctj4h/4/

Comment: What is the `width:1%;` for in `.nostretch`? I see it goes wrong if I set it to 0 but I don't get it.

Comment: the width is set to define a min-width for the cell. If it is smaller than the content, it will automatically expand the width. Table cells automatically do this by default. [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="test">test line</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

css::

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  div + div {
    flex: 1;
  }

  input {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

// unimportant bits
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```